# Image url works on development server but fails on production server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am working on an API application using Laravel 5.8 version. When a get request is made to the `products` api endpoint, I return a `ProductResource` collection which looks like this

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id'            => $this->id,
        'name'          => $this->name,
        'category'      => $this->category,
        'description'   => $this->description,
        'status'        => $this->status,
        'price'         => $this->price,
        'barrels'       => $this->barrels,
        'interest'      => $this->interest,
        'start'         => $this->start,
        'end'           => $this->end,
        'hidden'        => $this->hidden,
        'imageUrl'      => asset('storage/images/products/' . $this->image->name)
    ];
}
```

The challenge I am having is that on my local server clicking the returned `imageUrl` displays the correct image but in the staging environment, I get the default `404` not found page.

I created a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` on my local server which i am developing on to store the actual image file before uploading the app file to the staging environment. A quick check of the `storage/app/public/images/products` in the staging environment shows the image file but I still cannot view it from my browser. What could be the possible reason for this behavior?

Here's a sample of the resource in both my local and staging environments

Local/development server

```
{
    "id": 17,
    "name": "test",
    "category": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "status": "test",
    "price": 10990,
    "barrels": 207736,
    "interest": 0.2,
    "start": "2019-07-25",
    "end": "2019-08-25",
    "hidden": 0,
    "imageUrl": "http://localhost:8000/storage/images/products/pramopro_test_17.jpeg"
  }
```

Staging server

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "name": "test prod",
    "category": "test prod category",
    "description": "test prod description",
    "status": "loading",
    "price": 10000,
    "barrels": 300000,
    "interest": 0.2,
    "start": "2019-07-22",
    "end": "2019-08-28",
    "hidden": 0,
    "imageUrl": "http://staging.pramopro.com/storage/images/products/pramopro_testprod_13.jpeg"
  }
```

Comment: when you deploy, you need to run php artisan storage:link again

Comment: Really? Why, considering I simply copied the same files from development to the VPS?

Comment: yes, well its different path where the symlink create from development and vps path, 
 -rm -rf current public/storage , then run php artisan storage:link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make symlink to your storage folder 
like this:

```
ln -s ../project/storage/app/public storage
```

you will run it into your website files not into `public_html` folder

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was caused because I forgot to copy the `public/storage` folder to `public_html` when I copied a fresh copy of the app from my development server to the host VPS.